# How to use target_blank that works in a search field?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code from a search field, I tried several ways, but none worked. Someone can help?

```
<form id="searchResultsForm" name="searchResultsForm" method="get" action="#" target="_blank">

  <div class="search">
    <input class="tftextinput3" type="text" id="searchresultsquery" placeholder="Encontre tudo onde lhe for mais útil.." name="q" title="" autofocus>

    <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#resultsmodal">
      <button type="button" onclick="botaoazul()" class="searchButton2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="&nbsp;Descubra campanhas e jogue. Boa-sorte!">
        <i class="fa fa-tag fa-lg"></i>
      </button>
    </span>

    <button type="submit" class="searchButton" \ data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Insira um betcode e jogue. Boa-sorte!">
      <i class="fa fa-play fa-lg"></i>
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you sure that form gets submitted “normally” in the first place - and that there is not some JavaScript interfering, like canceling the normal form submit, to make a request in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did with the target="_blank" is ok and that it how is should be done.
However, other things in your code should be done differently:

1. Instead of button type="submit" => go with: input type="submit" (and no need for closing tag of input).
2. You forgot to add  a  in order to close the exiting one.
3. As for the form type="GET". It is usually a type="POST", so just take into consideration if that is what you really wanted.

Here is the final code (you can add all things i've dropped:

```
<form id="searchResultsForm" name="searchResultsForm" method="get" action="#" target="_blank">
     <div class="search">
        <input class="tftextinput3" type="text" id="searchresultsquery"  placeholder="Encontre tudo onde lhe for mais útil.."  name="q" title="" autofocus>
        <input type="submit" class="searchButton">
     </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not working. it always works like _self... I don't understand what you mean by:
nstead of => go with: (and no need for).
You forgot to add a in order to close the exiting one.

Comment: edited my comment. now you can see what i wrote. I've tested my code and it performs the post on a new tab, so check in a different browser, and if it works in a different browser, reset the configurations of the browser that is giving you troubles.